# VPN between 2 Mikrotik routers and static IP using LTE USB Modem

Tags: vpn, mikrotik, l2tp

I am trying to setup a VPN tunnel between two sites. Both sites are using a Mikrotik U951 with two Jazz 4G modems. Each 4G service has been allocated a static IP.

The main problem is that I am trying to create an L2TP connection but I can only see the LTE interface in the list of interfaces in Winbox and I can't create a PPP Client using the LTE interface as the list box shows "unknown" in red color.

So I need to find a way to connect our branches using the most efficient method.

Our main office is using the below IP details:
LAN: 192.168.0.0/24
Public IP: 192.0.2.11

And our branch office is using the below IP details:
LAN: 192.168.11.0/24
Public IP: 198.51.100.11

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mikrotik's [Ethernet over IP (EoIP)](https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=24805521) to create a very simple IP tunnel between sites. You can then bridge the interfaces at both sites with the local networks to create one network between both, or you can configure it as a routed tunnel.

It also has the ability to do encryption of the tunnel, to secure traffic and prevent snooping. You can get away with only one end having a static IP address, however it is preferable for both ends to be static.